# Dell Soundbar scratchy sound after some time on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04

Sound presents. Still on my Dell AC511 USB Soundbar is scratchy from time to time.

How to reproduce:

1. make active Dell AC511 (Digital or Analog doesn't matter) active
   device for output in Settings=>Sound
2. start playing sound (tried with Rhythmbox and Youtube inside
   browser)
3. sound is playing nice for about 30 seconds, after that it becomes
   scratchy and much more loud. After some time (about 15 seconds) it
   becomes again normal, after that again scratchy and repeat again.
   Switch time is not constant, it changes.
4. if I Digital Output was selected and sound became scratchy then 
   switching to analog output helps for about 30 seconds and circle
   starts again

It looks like the problem is with the output volume - when sound becomes loud and scratchy I can decrease volume in sound settings and that helps, but in several seconds it becomes silent so I need to increase it. If don't change the sound level then after been silent it will be restored and after that again silent in circle.

On Xonar DS which is installed on the same machine with headphones plugged in there is no such effect and sound is perfect. Haven't try built-in audio.

please help
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the connection between the soundbar and device
Check for damaged the wiring, (damage may be internal so if you have a spare cable then test it out and see if the spare works)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Checked. Connection is good - it's just a single usb cable. Before Ubuntu installation there was Windows7 and sound was fine as well. Anyway will check with other ports, thank you again

Comment: well its could be volume, a high volume can lead to distortion and scratchy sound so try setting the volume all the way up with audio playing then turn it down if it is scratchy when its vol is up then that may be your cause

Comment: I just changed usb port then plugged in to the old on, and it works. OMG, it's connection!!! F..k!!! Googled everywhere, reinstalled linux. Thank you!